# Using a regular expression in JavaScript, how do I group my matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

The following code:

```js
console.log("WatchGuard Technologies (SophosUK) - NDAM - 2003Jan29".match(/[\W]/gi));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Produces

```
[ ' ', ' ', '(', ')', ' ', '-', ' ', ' ', '-', ' ' ]
```

How do I modify my regular expression so that all the characters between the alpha-numeric characters are grouped together? In other words, I would like the output to be:

```
[ ' ', ' (',  ') - ', ' - ']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow matching more than one character per match with the `+` quantifier:

```
.match(/\W+/g)
```

```js
console.log(
  "WatchGuard Technologies (SophosUK) - NDAM - 2003Jan29".match(/\W+/g)
);
```

Comment: Note that `\W` does not include underscore (`_`) so if you want to group underscores with the other non-alphanumeric characters you would have to use a character set of `[^A-Za-z0-9]` instead of `\W`.